# solving boundary value problems numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im trying to obtain a solution of

$$ 0.1 y'' + (1+x)^2 y'  + y = 0 , \; \; \; \; y(0)=y(1)=1$$

and $0<x<1$.

Ive been trying to solve this in Matlab but there does not seem to be a built in function that does that. or is it?

Comment: Did you look at all at the documentation of Matlab? https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/boundary-value-problems.html

Comment: The problem is linear, you can find the solution with 2 calls to an initial value ODE solver for $(y(0),y'(0))=(1,0)$ and $(y(0),y'(0))=(1,1)$.

Comment: the solution of your equation is given by a nonelementary function

Comment: I consider this on-topic because there is a strong connection with a mathematical topic (how to solve a boundary value problem rather than an initial value problem), and @LutzL has made two appropriate Comments.  But the [Computational Science (scicomp) SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) has a more narrowly targeted Readership for such topics.  This (more difficult) [Question in particular](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8048/how-do-i-solve-a-boundary-value-ode-in-matlab) got migrated from Math.SE and has a couple of useful Answers.

Comment: The topic in itself is on-topic. The question in its current form is off-topic as it does not show the efforts and competency of the poster to gather relevant information and how it may apply to the question. The on-site Matlab documentation can be searched to find the `bvp` methods. The first links a web search turns up is the MathWorks pages on BVP problems and solution methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab's cousin Scilab one can obtain the solution using two ODE integrations as

```
eps = 0.1

function dydx = prime(x,y)
    dydx = [ y(2); -1/eps*(y(1)+(1+x)^2*y(2)) ]
endfunction

y0 = ode( [1;0],0,[1], prime);
y1 = ode( [1;1],0,[1], prime);
// 1 = y0(1)+v*(y1(1)-y0(1))
v = (1-y0(1,1))/(y1(1,1)-y0(1,1))

x = 0:0.02:1
y = ode( [1;v],0,x, prime);


eps1 = 1.2*eps
x_inn = (0:0.1:1)*2*eps1
y_inn = 1+ (exp(0.5)-1)*(1-exp(-x_inn/eps))
x_out = eps1+(1-eps1)*x
y_out = exp(1.0 ./ (1+x_out)-0.5)

clf(); plot(x,y(1,:), x_inn,y_inn, x_out, y_out)
```

Comment: Im trying to plot xout = 0:0.02:1
yout = exp(1 ./(1+xin) -0.5)+eps*exp(1 ./(xin+1) -0.5)*(1/(2(1+xin)^2) + 1/(5(1+xin)^3) -(3/80)*(1+xin)^2);

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: You should use the x-segment `x_out` for the outer solution to parametrize the outer solution. Also, your formula seems wrong, where did the factor $(1+x)^2$ after the integration come from?

Comment: but, how is the syntax in scilab? Im trying to plot, but it is not working. it says to check the parenthesis. How do I type a complicted function into scilab?

Comment: If you have Matlab and know it well, it is easier to adapt the code to that (`endfunction` to `end`, `ode` to `ode45` with re-arranged arguments). In scilab I always use the editor for more than a handful of connected lines. It also indicates parenthesis pairs.

Comment: how would you plot the difference of the two functions? Im trying $error = abs( yuni - y) $ but when I execute it says inconsistent substraction

Comment: Inspect the format of the two arrays. Most probably you need to transpose one of them